# How can I make a system to notify a user if changes have been made to content after it was submitted?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, hash, data-integrity

I need to make a feature that will notify a user if the content in the database has changed since it was inserted. I assume it would work somewhat like an eSignature. The two solutions I have come up with (comparing duplicated data and comparing hashes of the data) seem to be relatively inefficient.

Is there a better or more standardized way of doing this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an another column named `isEdited` in you contents_table with default value of `0`. In any update api, you should modify `isEdited` to `1` silently from server-side itself. I think this will be standard method even which I use in production level applications.

In client-side, use that isEdited key to indicate users whether the content is edited or not. Thats it.

Any improvements on this is appreciated :)